# Which replacement standard recovery diodes do I use for a high voltage full bridge rectifier in a valve guitar amplifier?

Tags: power-supply, diodes, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

The original diodes were four IN4007 (1A 1000V PRRV.)

If I replace them with IN5408RGL (STANDARD DIODE, 3A, 1KV PRRV,) basically upping the current to 3A, will this have any detrimental effect on the circuit following the diodes?

My understanding is that the circuit will draw the current it needs and, so long as the diode are large enough ampere wise, over sizing will make no difference. In other words the role of the diode is not to regulate voltage or current but simply to rectify AC to DC.

Is this correct?

Comment: I think the part numbers are 1N4007 and 1N5408, not IN4007 and IN5408.

Comment: What is the DC voltage being rectified? The diodes need to withstand double that voltage.

Answer (score 3):

This should be fine. The forward voltage drop of the 1N5408 is 100mV higher, but that shouldn't be particularly significant here.

If you're worried, you should be able to pick up an exact 1N4007 replacement easily, though. They're an extremely common part that you can get on eBay as well as all well-known electronics distributors.

Comment: Voltage drop at the same current and Tj should be lower for the. 1N540x, not that it matters.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pretty common repair strategy to replace failed elements with higher-rated ones. Rectifier diodes in a mains frequency power supply stage are very good candidates.

What can go wrong:

1. Especially in an audio-related device: you may get a hum that was not there in the first place.

The probability is very low and usually happens when one uses different type of diodes - e.g. modern Silicon diodes instead of the original valve diode,  Germanium diode (from the dawn if the semiconductor era) or [Selenium diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_rectifier) (from the valve era).

2. Increased inrush current may break some other element in the circuit. Or the diodes themselves.

This, too, happens mainly when replacing SE diodes.

3. The rectifier voltage increasing or decreasing a bit.

Also related to using different type of diodes and is important in low-voltage circuits.

Points 1 and 2 are important to consider when repairing a "tube" things because the diodes you intend to replace may have been replaced in the past (either in a previous repair or in a medicore attempt of a circuit redesign/optimization by the manufacturer)